# Zuul proxy server throwing Internal Server Error when request takes more time to process

Tags: microservices, netflix-zuul, proxy-server

[Zuul Proxy Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xz2G.png)

I am getting this error when the request takes more time to process in the service.But Zuul returns response of Internal Server Error

Using zuul 2.0.0.RC2 release

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, in case of a service not responding, a missing route, etc. you can setup the /error endpoint to deliver a custom response to the user.
For example:

```
@Controller
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/error", produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity error(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // consider putting these in a try catch
        Integer statusCode = (Integer)request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
        Throwable exception = (Throwable)request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");

        // maybe add some error logging here, e.g. original status code, exception, traceid, etc.

        // consider a better error to the user here
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("{'message':'some error happened', 'trace_id':'some-trace-id-here'}");
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }
}
```